# JavaScript Edit Local Client Time?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code that displays the local time of the computer, and I need to adjust it to our buildings clock time. I need to have it output the client's local time, but then add 2 minutes to it, so it matches the clocks throughout the building. Here's my code.

## EDIT

If my question wasn't obvious enough, how could I modify the local time output to add 2 minutes to the outputted time? Quote I need to have it output the client's local time, but then add 2 minutes to it, so it matches the clocks throughout the building.

```js
var setTime = setInterval(function() {
  clock()
}, 1000)

function clock() {
  var d = new Date();
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}
window.onload = function()  {
  clock();
}
```

```css
.date, h2 p  {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 200%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.date h2  {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.date p  {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background: linear-gradient(#101010, #151515, #101010);
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: white;
  width: 875px;
  font-size: 225%;
}
.select  {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 125%;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 25px;
  padding: 0;
}
#instruct  {
  float: left;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 110%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 169px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 400px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
h4  {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="date">
    <h2>Time</h2>
    <br>
    <p id="time"></p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why are the clocks in your building 2 minutes fast?

Comment: It's not, there's just separate times for clock-in/clock-out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getMinutes` and `setMinutes` on the time returned by `new Date()`.

```js
var setTime = setInterval(function() {
  clock()
}, 1000)

function clock() {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + 2); // Add 2 minutes
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}
window.onload = function()  {
  clock();
}
```

```css
.date, h2 p  {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 200%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.date h2  {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.date p  {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background: linear-gradient(#101010, #151515, #101010);
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: white;
  width: 875px;
  font-size: 225%;
}
.select  {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 125%;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 25px;
  padding: 0;
}
#instruct  {
  float: left;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 110%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 169px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 400px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
h4  {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="date">
    <h2>Time</h2>
    <br>
    <p id="time"></p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Will this work across hours? For example, won't `setMinutes` this turn `04:59`  to `04:01` instead of `05:01`?

Comment: No, the date functions are smart about wraparound.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTime` to increase the timestamps up by 2 seconds.

```
function clock() {
  var d = new Date();
  // Set the time from date to be 2 seconds more than it is currently
  // (1000ms * 60s * 2)
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 2));
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}
```